# How to adjust Node.js build script to first build and then launch server

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following simple batch file "bld.cmd" script for easier testing, it first compiles stuff and then starts server. Problem is that "npm run build"  (line 1) never returns, so I had to add start "start" prefix to open a second window for that and keep running build after 6 secs.

```
start npm run build
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
npm run dev
```

My question is,  how can I make the line 1 (1st window) go away when I close the running server with CTRL+C  or  optionally how to adjust this script so that there is no need for starting line 1 in another window.

```
{   "main": "index.js",   "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "start": "nodemon server/index.js"   },
```

Comment: Start /WAIT did not work.. other ideas?

Comment: you mean  something like `"build": "webpack --progress --colors & npm run start"` ??

Comment: Dayan thanks I edited "scripts" like this but "runall" still not working: {
     "runall": "webpack --progress --colors & nodemon server/index.js --exec babel-node",
 "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "start": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },

Answer (score 0):

My assesment is that `npm` is actually running either `npm.bat` or `npm.cmd`. For that reason I would suggest you `Call` that batch file/Windows NT command script instead.

```
Call npm run build
Rem Timeout 5 >Nul
npm run dev
```

`Call` will run one batch program from another, returning to the calling batch file upon completion of the called one. If there are further commands below the last line in your posted script content then precede that command with `Call` too. I have `Rem`arked the the command `Timeout`, *(`Ping` in your example)*, as it is unlikely necessary.

*See `Call /?` for its usage information*

Comment: Thanks I added Call, but the 1st. script still hangs after these rows until CTRL+C is pressed.
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module

Comment: @Tom, the question was about how to make the batch file return and not start the `npm` process in a new window, my answer solves that. I cannot do anything about your build process or about you force closing it with Ctrl-C; that is outside of the scope of your question.